# Escrever arquivo no excel dentro do projeto Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Tenho uma Spider que pega os links xlsx, na Request eu chamo os arquivos e salvo em:

```
def save_file(self, response):

    f = open("teste.xls", "wb")

    f = write(response.body)

    f.close()
```

Porém retorna o erro:

```
f = write(response.body)
```

> NameError: name 'write' is not defined

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: Não deveria ser `f.write`? Você precisa chamar um método, não sobrescrever o objeto.

Comment: Verdade cara, obrigado já deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save_file(self, response):

f = open("teste.xls", "wb")

f.write(response.body)

f.close()
```

Você errou em

```
f = write(response.body)
```

você atribuiu a váriavel "f" o valor write(), mas write não é uma função.

Comment: Richard, procure explicar o que fez, se não a pessoa pode não entender.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica